# Golang - Effective test of multiple packages

Tags: unit-testing, go

I want to execute all tests from my application, now I do it with command:

```
go test ./app/...
```

Unfortunately it takes quite a long time, despite that single tests run quite fast. I think that the problem is that `go` needs to compile every package (with its dependence) before it runs tests.

I tried to use `-i` flag, it help a bit but still I'm not satisfied with the testing time.

```
go test -i ./app/... 
go test ./app/...
```

Do you have any better idea how to efficiently test multiple packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the nature of `go test`: it builds a special runtime with addition code to execute (this is how it tracks code coverage).

If it isnt fast enough, you have two options:

1) use bash tooling to compile a list of packages (e.g. using `ls`), and then execute them each individually in parallel.  There exists many ways to do this in bash.

The problem with this approach is that the output will be interleaved and difficult to track down failures.

2) use the `t.Parallel()` flag with each of your tests to allow the test runtime to execute in parallel.  Since Go 1.5, `go test` runs with `GOMAXPROCS` set to the number of cores on your CPU which allows for concurrently running tests. Tests are still ran synchronously by default.  You have to set the `t.Parallel()` flag for each test, telling the runtime it is OK to execute this test in parallel.

The problem with this approach being that it assumes you followed best practices and have used SoC/decoupling, don't have global states that would mutate in the middle of another test, no mutex locks (or very few of them), no race condition issues (use `-race`), etc.

--

Opinion: Personally, I setup my IDE to run `gofmt` and `go test -cover -short` on every Save.  that way, my code is always formatted and my tests are run, only within the package I am in, telling me if something failed.  The `-cover` flag works with my IDE to show me the lines of code that have been tested versus not tested. The `-short` flag allows me to write tests that I know will take a while to run, and within those tests I can check `t.Short()` bool to see if I should `t.Skip()` that test.  There should be packages available for your favorite IDE to set this up (I did it in Sublime, VIM and now Atom).

That way, I have instant feedback within the package I m editing.

Before I commit the code, I then run all tests across all packages.  Or, I can just have the C.I. server do it.

Alternatively, you can make use of the `-short` flag and `build tags` (e.g. `go test -tags integration`) to refactor your tests to separate your Unit tests from Integration tests.  This is how I write my tests:

- test that are fast and can run in parallel <- I make these tests run by default with `go test` and `go test -short`.
- slow tests or tests that require external components, I require addition input to run, like `go test -tags integration` is required to run them. This pattern does not run the integration tests with a normal `go test`, you have to specify the additional tag. I don't run the integration tests across the board either.  That's what my CI servers are for.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow a consistent name scheme for your tests you can easily reduce the number of them you execute by using the `-run` flag.

Quoting from `go help testflag`:

> -run regexp
>
> Run only those tests and examples matching the regular expression.

So let's say you have 3 packages: `foo`, `bar` and `qux`. Tests of those packages are all named like `TestFoo..`, `TestBar..` and `TestQux..` respectively.

You could do `go test -run '^Test(Foo|Bar)*' ./...` to run only tests from `foo` and `bar` package.